# Can I share a TV card?

Tags: server, networking, tv-tuner, mediaserver, home-server

My environment:

- 2 PCs, a desktop and a laptop, both on Oneiric
- they are connected together by ethernet wire
- nfs-common is installed and configured: the desktop is the server
- a TV tuner card is installed on the desktop, I can watch TV with the software [Me-TV](https://launchpad.net/me-tv)

It works fine, TV on desktop, and my network too: I share folders thanks to NFS.

But I would like more:

How can I share my TV tuner card from the desktop and be able to watch TV on the laptop too?

If possible I would like a solution that allows me to **keep using the software Me-TV**, on both PCs. 
I bet that there is a solution to create a fake TV card on the 2nd PC with [xNBD](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/xnbd-server.8.html).

I'm trying `xnbd-server --target /dev/dvb/adapter0/demux0` but I cant make it work.

Trying to understand some [examples of xNBD](http://bitbucket.org/hirofuchi/xnbd/wiki/Home) command lines, it seems to be meant only for sharing disk player.
**If someone as ever used xNBD, he's welcome.**

Answer (score 1):

Install mythtv. It is a television recording/watching program with many features and network sharing.

Comment: I tried it, but I found it too complicated. I'm looking for a simple solution that would allow me to create a "ghost" of TV card on the other PC (create a fake `/dev/something`). So then I could keep using Me-tv or any other simple software (VLC, ...)

Comment: Yes, mythtv is extremely complicated, you might want to look at internet tutorials.

Comment: could suggest me any good tutorials ? I found this http://parker1.co.uk/mythtv_ubuntu.php

Comment: I am currently trying to get my card working with mythtv as I type this, and I have been at it for weeks. It's gonna take some work.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a solution with VLC. VLC makes it possible to stream content to another computer in your netwerk. Open VLC and Choose Media -> Stream (CTRL s)